# c++ output formatting problems

Tags: c++, file, formatting, output

I have a list of names in a 2-D array. My program performs some computations and assign these names their respective marks. I am supposed to send the output to a file but I am facing some problems. The problem is the length of each name in the array varies and it has affected my output format. I am looping through the array to print out the names and their values. The output comes nicely when I omit the name.

```
Name of Pupils/Students     Indiv-Test      Group Work      Class T.               
                               4                3                2                
                               6               15               12
```

But as soon as I bring the names, then the output changes.

```
 Name of Pupils/Students    Indiv-Test      Group Work      Class T.
1.nana yaw kwadwo                               15              14               13                                                         1
2.kwaku                                  12              15               15         
3.osei kofi                                  12              14                1
```

So it is the length of the names that affect my output format. Please is there any way, I can get a nice output format like my first sample output together with the names; like this. Still maintaining the length of my names. Highly required.Thank you in advance.

```
 Name of Pupils/Students    Indiv-Test      Group Work      Class T.               
 1.nana yaw kwadwo              4              3              2                
 2.kwaku                        6              15             12   
 3.osei kofi                    12             14             1
```

I have tried every output format I know but yet still.
This is my sample code;

```
for (int n=0;n<=num;n++)
{
name_output<<n+1<<"."<<sample[n];
name_output<<setw(37)<<s.indiv_test[n]<<setw(16)<<s.grp_work[n]<<setw(17) <<s.class_test[n]
}
```

Comment: you use `setw` for every entry, why not for the first?

Comment: @idclev463035818, If I don't do it for every entry. The values wouldn't be nicely placed under the respective headers.

Comment: That's not what they asked you.

Comment: ...but you are not doing it for every entry and that is the reason the entries are not nicely placed under the repspective headers. `setw` applies to the next thing you print, you have one before `s.indiv_test` one before `grp_work` one before `class_test` but none before `sample`, why not?

Comment: @idclev 463035818, sample is the 2D array that contains those names.

Comment: The problem is my list of names are plenty, 50+.That's why I can't do it for every entry, have no choice than to loop. My reason why I can't manually set for every entry.

Comment: dont know how else to explain... why do you not have `... setw(42) <<sample[n];` ?

Comment: .. that would shift the names outside the ```names of pupils or students``` . I want the names to be directly under it.